# Understanding send and receive criteria for "Answered"

Tags: python, scapy, icmp

In this example:

```
>>> sr1(IP(dst="192.168.200.254")/ICMP())
Begin emission:
..Finished to send 1 packets.
.*
Received 97 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=28 id=1 flags= frag=0L ttl=255 proto=icmp chksum=0xa7c4 src=4.2.2.1 dst=172.16.20.40 options=[] |<ICMP  type=echo-reply code=0 chksum=0xffff id=0x0 seq=0x0 |<Padding |>>>
```

What criteria does Scapy use to separate packets into these 3 categories?
(Received, answered, remaining)

As well, is there any way to access the received packets? It seems like this function only returns the answered packets.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation function sr1 only return one packet that answered the packet. If you want to collect/manipulate received and answered packets you should use the function sr() which is for sending packets and receiving answers. The function returns a couple of packet and answers, and the unanswered packets. For example:

```
>>> ans, unans=sr(IP(dst="192.168.0.1") / ICMP())
Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.
*
Received 2 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

returns answered and unanswered results lists. And answered results are pairs (packet sent, answer). So the following code:

```
>>> for snd, rcv in ans:
...         print("snd={} rcv={}".format(snd.summary(), rcv.summary()))
... 
snd=IP / ICMP 192.168.0.109 > 192.168.0.1 echo-request 0 rcv=IP / ICMP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.109 echo-reply 0
>>>
```

shows summary of answers: packet sent and packet received.

Comment: You're totally right. I'd add that you can directly use `ans.summary()` to get something close to your code.